# Divide values from selected rows from one column by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to **divide** values from the **'total_deaths' column** by the values from the **'total_cases' column** from **rows 0 to 634** and I want the result to show as a **new column named 'CFR'.**

This is what I have tried, but it divided all the values in both columns instead of only rows 0 to 634.

`data['CFR'] = np.round(data['total_deaths']/data['total_cases']*100,3)` 
[image: Preview of my output from the code above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accessor. Code below

```
data.loc[0:634,'CFR'] = np.round(data.loc[0:634,'total_deaths']/data.loc[0:634,'total_cases']*100,3)
```

Comment: How would I find the absolute difference between values from 'total_cases' column and 'new_cases' columns but again only from rows 0 to 634 and have it show as a new column 'Difference'. 

I have started with the code below, but it does it for all the rows, instead of only 0 to 634. 
data['Difference']=np.absolute(data[total_cases]-data['new_cases'])